# Add dimension numpy array

Tags: arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays such as:

```
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])

b = np.array([101, 102, 103 ])
```

I want to create a new array with shape (len(a), 2), such as

```
array([[1, 101], [2, 102], [3, 103]])
```

How can I do it with numpy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so called `column_stack`

```
np.column_stack((a,b))
Out[309]: 
array([[  1, 101],
       [  2, 102],
       [  3, 103]])
```

Comment: @Alex yw :-) happy coding :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:

```
np.c_[a,b]
```

will do the job as well.